# write() method not recognizing TextArea

Tags: java, menu, filewriter, bufferedwriter, writer

I've written an `ActionListener` for a toolbar menu item which is called "Save", on click I want the program to save the content of `TextArea` l1 into a .txt file called "filename", so this si the code that I've come up with (since the program is really long, I've pasted here only the code fragments where the error is located or might be located):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

...

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

class Progetto extends Frame {
...

  private TextArea l1 = new TextArea();
  ...

  private MenuBar menubar;
  private Menu file;
  private MenuItem save;

  ...

  salva.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
          BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt"));
          l1.write(fileOut);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
```

When I run this program I get the following error:

```
Error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method write(java.io.BufferedWriter)
location: variable l1 of type java.awt.TextArea
```

I've looked everywhere in the documentation and forums, but I can't understand why this error occurs neither how to solve it...

What can I do to fix this error?

**EDIT**
The `TextArea` looks like this:

```
Jack: 9.0
Mark: 9.0
Nick: 1.0
Linn: 6.5
Jhon: 3.5
```

Comment: Are you certain `TextArea` has a method `write`? If it does, [it is not well documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TextArea.html). The compiler recognizes `l1` just fine. It can not, however, locate an method `write` for it.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? you want to write a `BufferedWriter` to a `TextArea` ? or do you want to read something from a file and write it to a `TextArea` ?

Comment: @svasa I have the `TextArea` `l1` with a text written inside and I want to save that as a separare .txt file, so as an example, if on the `TextArea` I have this:   
I    
am    
java  
I want the .txt file to be:  I  am  java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code inside action listener to :

```
salva.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
          String text = l1.getText();
          if ( text != null  && !text.isEmpty() )
          {
             String[] lines = text.split("\n");
             BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt"));
             for ( String line : lines )
             {

                fileOut.write( line, 0, line.length()-1 );
                fileOut.newLine();
             }

             fileOut.close();
          }


        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried something similar to this before, the problem with this code is that It places all the text in a single line, while the `TextArea` I1 is written in different lines, so I would like the .txt file to be in the same format.

Comment: @TobiaZamò updated answer. Also your question seems to be completely irrelevant to the problem you specified. please update your question.

Comment: `String lines = text.split("\n");` the console returns an error for incompatoble types from `String` to `String[]`

Comment: Now it says there is an error on `fileOut.close()`: cannot find symbol; if I remove it, the txt document created is literally empty...

Comment: Ok , it has to be outside the for loop. Try updated answer.

Comment: Almost there svasa, now unfortunately it still prints everything in a single line in the .txt, I'm updating the question to display how the `TextArea` should look like

Comment: I already updated the answer. Include `fileOut.write("\n");` in your loop

Comment: I did, it still prints everything in a single line, I'm tring to modify the code aswell but I can't figure out what prevents it from creating new lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117632/discussion-between-tobia-zamo-and-svasa).